# How could I permanently remove files if I have already modify `rm` as moving files into a trash can?

Tags: linux, bash

In order to implement a trash can like that in Windows, I add the following code to `~/.bashrc`:

`rm() { mv $@ ~/.trash_can; }`

now I want to empty my trash, but `rm -rf` does not work, because `rm` has already been modified. What should I do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `rm`?

Comment: @fateddy You mean using `/bin/rm`?

Comment: Yes - basically whatever `which rm` returns.

Comment: You should definitely **use more quotes**: please write your function as `rm() { mv -- "$@" ~/.trash_can; }`. The quotes will help you when you use this function with filenames containing spaces or glob characters; the leading `--` will be useful when you have filenames with leading hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
'rm' filename.foo
```

Quoting a command using apostrophes prevents alias substitution.

Comment: Or \rm filename.foo see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29#Overriding_aliases

Comment: Quoting does *not* suppress function lookup (neither single quotes nor backslashes). `command` will work.